# Detecting sys.exit() and ValueError from a python script in bash script

Tags: python, unix, error-handling

I created a bash script that manages multiple related python scripts based on specific conditions (i.e., run this script while file has < x number of lines, run a different script if..., etc.). I am using entry points to execute these python scripts within the bash script.

When validating the bash script I found some edge cases where all the conditions fail, resulting in a `sys.exit(load_entry_point('Program', 'console_scripts', 'iter')())` and `ValueError: Nothing was generated` (designated within the python program to be raised if nothing happens).

After looking on SO, I tried something like this within some of my conditionals:

```
    if [ $? -ne 0 ];
    then
        echo "exit 1"
    fi
    echo "EXIT 0"
```

I continue to get `EXIT 0`, suggesting no errors are being detected. What I am not understanding here?

For clarity, my goal is to detect any errors thrown by the invoked python scripts to have the bash script respond accordingly.

---

Here is an idea of what the bash script is like:

```
Iter=1
while [ $nr_lines -lt 17 ]; do

    if [ $Iter -eq 5 ]; then

        echo ''
        echo 'Relax parameter. Iteration:' $Iter

        relax -i $Iter -o ./dir

        nr_lines=$(wc -l < ./dir/output$Iter.csv)
        
        let Iter++

    else

        echo ''
        echo 'Iteration:' $Iter

        iter -i $Iter -o ./dir

        nr_lines=$(wc -l < ./dir/output$Iter.csv)
        
        let Iter++
    fi
done
```

I have tried putting the conditional for error capturing here:

```
Iter=1
while [ $nr_lines -lt 17 ]; do

    if [ $Iter -eq 5 ]; then

        echo ''
        echo 'Relax parameter. Iteration:' $Iter

        relax -i $Iter -o ./dir

        nr_lines=$(wc -l < ./dir/output$Iter.csv)
        
        let Iter++

    else

        echo ''
        echo 'Iteration:' $Iter

        iter -i $Iter -o ./dir

        nr_lines=$(wc -l < ./dir/output$Iter.csv)
        
        let Iter++
    fi

    if [ $? -ne 0 ];
    then
        echo "exit 1"
    fi
    echo "EXIT 0"

done
```

and here:

```
Iter=1
while [ $nr_lines -lt 17 ]; do

    if [ $Iter -eq 5 ]; then

        echo ''
        echo 'Relax parameter. Iteration:' $Iter

        relax -i $Iter -o ./dir

        nr_lines=$(wc -l < ./dir/output$Iter.csv)
        
        let Iter++

    else

        echo ''
        echo 'Iteration:' $Iter

        iter -i $Iter -o ./dir

        nr_lines=$(wc -l < ./dir/output$Iter.csv)
        
        let Iter++
    fi

done

if [ $? -ne 0 ];
then
    echo "exit 1"
fi
echo "EXIT 0"
```

and both return `EXIT 0`, suggesting no errors have occurred.

Comment: You're calling `sys.exit()` with too many arguments.

Comment: If the script exits due to an unhandled exception, `$?` should be non-zero. Please show more context around the conditional.

Comment: You can also use `if python scriptname.py; then echo "exit 0"; else echo "exit non-zero"; fi`

Comment: Does the script have a `try/except` that prints the error and continues. That will prevent the shell from seeing the failure exit.

Comment: @Barmar I edited my post, I had typed the error incorrectly. This program works perfectly fine, it is the bash script that is problematic.

Comment: That's why I asked you to show more of the bash script. Maybe you're doing something before the `if` that's clearing `$?`.

Comment: @Barmar the python script does not have ```try/except```.

Comment: Please post a [mre].

Comment: @Barmar I have updated the main post to show generally how the script works.

Comment: Where is the bash script calling the Python script? And where is the `if` statement that checks `$?`?

Comment: @Barmar The python scripts are being called using entry points "iter" and "relax". I removed the block with the ```if``` statement that checks ```$?```. I had tested it within the ```while``` loop and outside of it as well.

Comment: But the whole point was to see how the `if` statement fits into the whole script, to see what you might be doing wrong.

Comment: @Barmar I have edited the post to reflect where I have tried to capture the error.

Comment: Well, that's clearly wrong. You have to check `$?` immediately after the command that might fail. Not after the loop is done.

Comment: `$?` gets reset after every command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
        iter -i $Iter -o ./dir
```

to

```
        if ! iter -i $Iter -o ./dir
        then
            echo "iter failed"
            break
        fi
```

This directly tests the exit status of the python script run by `iter`. If it exits with a non-zero status, you print the message and break out of the `while` loop.

You can do similarly with `relax`.